# How to call std::forward when type is known

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, constants, move-semantics

I have the following piece of code:

```
class Game {
private:
    const Ruleset& rules;
public:
    Game(const Ruleset&);
}

public class Ruleset {
public:
    virtual ~Ruleset();
    virtual bool isMoveValid(Move&) const = 0;
}
```

Now the following initilializer works fine:

```
Game::Game(const Ruleset& r) : rules(r) {}
```

but I just found out that this doesn't protect me against dangling references to temporaries. I thought of the following solution:

```
class Game {
private:
    const Ruleset& rules;
public:
    Game(const Ruleset&);
    Game(const Ruleset&&) = delete;
}
```

The problem with this code is that I have many variations of constructors for Game in reality and I want to avoid to delete every other one specifically so I want something like

```
class Game {
private:
    const Ruleset rules;
public:
    Game(const Ruleset&&);
}

Game::Game(const Ruleset& r) : rules(forward(r)) {}
```

possibly with more copied/moved arguments. Let's say I have a constructor with 4 arguments:

```
Constructor(type1&, type2&, type3&, type4&).
```

Then I want to use move-constructor when possible but I don't want to code every variation of Constructor(type1&&, type2&, type3&, type4&), etc...

Is this possible? (Of course the Ruleset-class has to declare move constructors now). Also point out when you have a better approach to the problem that helps me to code this class efficiently.

Comment: The constructor signatures in your "I want something like" code don't match, and it's not clear what you're hoping it would do

Comment: `std::forward(r)` is never valid, you **must** give a template argument list. Maybe you just want `Game(RuleSet r) : rules(std::move(r)) { }` which will do a copy and a move if passed an lvalue, or two moves if passed an rvalue.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I overthought it, std::move should work fine in this case? How does it work though, I thought move casts it to an rvalue in every case, how does this call the copy constructor?

Comment: The copy constructor can get called to initialize `r`, then `rules` is always initialized by the move constructor.

Comment: Wait can you store a RulesSet by value? That changes the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only accept lvalues, you can just write a constructor that does that:

```
Game(RuleSet& r)
: rules(r)
{ }
```

That way you just can't pass in temporaries easily, and you can still take a `const&` to what's passed.

You could also take every argument by universal ref and forward each argument one-by-one. This will also hide the `const` aspect and force your `rules` member to be a `const RulesSet*` instead of a reference:

```
template <typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
Game(Arg1&& a1, Arg2&& a2)
{
    initRulesSet(std::forward<Arg1>(a1));
    initSomethingElse(std::forward<Arg2>(a2));
}

void initRulesSet(RulesSet&& ) = delete;
void initRulesSet(const RulesSet& rs) { rules = &rs; }
```

Comment: Doesn't that take away some security for the user? They can't trust that RuleSet is used const only now, can they?

Comment: @WorldSEnder Yes. But you really only have three options: (1) You can write 2^N constructors (2) You can write lvalue-only constructors (3) You can write universal-ref constructors that forward each argument individually, which still kind of hides the const part.